# Django options has no attribute _name_map

Tags: python, django

I have a table in database:

models.py

```
class Board(models.Model):
 ...
```

Now from python shell (manage.py shell), I can do:

```
Board._meta._name_map
```

But I can't access it in my views.py:

```
a = Board._meta._name_map
```

Error:

```
'Options' object has no attribute '_name_map'
```

There might be some other attributes missing too, so why is it?? How can I access this _name_map information?

Comment: Check this [Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9903) out. You cannot access the attribute until __after__ the object has been loaded. Use `get_field_by_name` instead

Comment: I read that ticket, but get_field_by_name doesn't do me any good here. I'm trying to check if a field in the table is ForeignKey or not with this code:

    for k,v in Board._meta._name_map.items():
  if isinstance(v[0],ForeignKey):
  k*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_name_map` is a cache, not something you can rely on.

I think you'll be better off with this:

```
for field in Board._meta.fields:
    if isinstance(field, ForeignKey):
        k = field.name
        # then whatever
```

At least assuming you don't already know the name of the field you're looking for, since you say `get_field_by_name` doesn't help.